# Eclipse RCP: NullPointer on getSite().setSelectionProvider(...)

Tags: eclipse, jface, rcp, e4

As I have done the following tutorials:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTableAdvanced/article.html

I wanted to combine the JFace table viewer (plugin from 2nd and 3rd tutorial) and the ToDo application from the first tutorial. In the JFace table example(s) there is a View extended from a ViewPart. In this the call:

getSite().setSelectionProvider(view)

inside the createPartControl method is fine and works.

But when I do the same in the other tutorial it does not work, I get a NullPointerException. The first article creates a plugin and then transform it using features and products into an Eclipse 4 application. So the classes in the application are not derived from a 'Part'. They are referenced using the application model and only use the annotation @PostConstruct.

**Why is it that I get this NullPointerException?**
And really, **how can I get the SelectionProvider service linked to the Workbench?**

I also tried to use PlatformUI.getWorkbench() but it says that the workbench does not yet exist.

Any help highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse 4 (e4) applications are completely different from traditional Eclipse 3.x style applications.

In an e4 application you cannot use a lot of things that are used in a Eclipse 3.x application - so you need to check which style the example you are using is based on. The e4 application has access to a lot of new features that are not available in a 3.x application.

In an e4 application you inject the `ESelectionService` to get and set the current selection.

Comment: Great - that's a very good hint ;-) - I completely missed that point. What I did now is add `@Inject private ESelectionService selectionService`

Comment: ... and added a ISelectionChangeListener with `viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() { @Overwrite public void selectionChanged(...) ` see [https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/EAS/Workbench_Services#Selection_Service]